# Docker - ERROR: unexpected EOF (Docker build not working)

Tags: mongodb, docker-compose, docker-build, laravel-10

I'm trying to build the docker-compose.yml file, but it's giving `ERROR: unexpected EOF` error.
Following is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
`version: '3.3'

services:
  app:
    build: .
    image: my-laravel-app
    container_name: php-laravel-container
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "8082:80"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/var/www/html/    
    environment:
      - APP_ENV=local
      - APP_DEBUG=true
  mongo:
    image: mongo:5.0
    container_name: laravel-mongo
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "27018:27018"
    volumes:
      - ./database/mongodb/db:/data/db
      - ./database/mongodb/dev.archive:/Databases/dev.archive
      - ./database/mongodb/production:/Databases/production
    command: [ --auth ]
  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    container_name: laravel-mongo-express
    environment:
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=root
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=password
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL=mongodb://root:password@mongo:27018/?authSource=admin
      - ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_USERNAME=mexpress
      - ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_PASSWORD=mexpress
    links:
      - mongo
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "8085:8085"`
```

And following is my docker file:

```
FROM composer:2 AS composer

RUN composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel /app

FROM php:8.1-apache

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y openssl zip unzip git curl
RUN apt-get install -y libzip-dev libonig-dev libicu-dev
RUN apt-get install -y autoconf pkg-config libssl-dev

RUN docker-php-ext-install bcmath mbstring intl opcache

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql mysqli

RUN pecl install mongodb
RUN echo "extension=mongodb.so" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/mongodb.ini

COPY --from=composer /app /var/www/html/
COPY --from=composer /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    zip \
    unzip \
    git \
    libpq-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install \
    pdo_mysql \
    && docker-php-ext-enable \
    pdo_mysql

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/storage \
    && chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/bootstrap/cache

RUN a2enmod rewrite && \
    sed -i 's!/var/www/html!/var/www/html/public!g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

RUN composer dump-autoload --optimize \
    && php artisan optimize

EXPOSE 8082

CMD ["apache2-foreground"]
```

I'm trying to create three different containers of the following images:

1. Laravel.
2. mongo.
3. mongo-express.

but it's is not building.
Suggest the best possible solution.

Laravel Version: 10
Docker Version: 24.0.5
OS: Ubuntu